# 『.pyファイル』を実行できません。

Tags: python, bottle

Pythonについて。

只今、『入門 Python3』を読みながら、
JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。

ファイルが見つからないというエラーが出てしまい、困っています。
以下、経緯を書きます。

```py
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def home() :
return "It isn't fancy, but it's my home page"

run(host = 'localhost', port = 9999)
```

これは、http://localhost:9999 にアクセスすると、`It isn't fancy, but it's my home page`という文字を表示させるものです。

昨日は問題なく、JupyterLabにて

```
python bottle1.
```

と書いて実行できましたが、今日は
SyntaxError: invalid syntaxと出て、
構文エラーを吐かれてしまいました。

コマンドプロンプトにて同じことをやると、
No such file or directory
と出ました。

何故、エラーが出てしまったのでしょうか？ 
また、bottle1.pyを実行するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「.py ファイルを実行できません」という件で

```
No such file or directory
```

についてなので、SyntaxError は脇に置きますが、

```
python bottle1.
```

ではなく、`bottle1.py` なら

```
python bottle1.py
```

とする必要があるでしょう。また、もちろん、コマンドを入力するカレントディレクトリは、`bottle1.py` と同じであるという前提の下で。違っていれば、ちゃんと cd で移動するか、path 付きで `bottle1.py` を指定する必要があります。